# Dependency problems when installing tidytext on R

Tags: r, tidytext

I am trying to install tidytext package on R 3.4.0 on OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.6). But doing so is giving the following errors with package mnormt (I don't understand 'm' flag!):

```
* installing *source* package ‘mnormt’ ...
** package ‘mnormt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/usr/local/bin/gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c biv-nt.f -o biv-nt.o
FATAL:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!
make: *** [biv-nt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/mnormt’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mnormt’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available for package ‘psych’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/psych’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘psych’ is not available for package ‘broom’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/broom’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘broom’ is not available for package ‘tidytext’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/tidytext’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidytext’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/9d/q1d4cyfs7yn7hk8tjmwyd1x00000gn/T/RtmpV6vyI0/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried installing tidytext with `install.packages("tidytext")` and possibly also with `devtools` but with no success also failing on `broom -> psych -> mnormt`.

Do you have any idea how to fix this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1945).

Comment: This is the actual, specific, error after installing mnormt: 
`* installing *source* package ‘mnormt’ ...
** package ‘mnormt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/usr/local/bin/gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c biv-nt.f -o biv-nt.o
FATAL:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!
make: *** [biv-nt.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/mnormt’`

Answer (score 1):

OK I solved it myself. Just do as follows if you encounter it:

```
curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /
```